# TinyMCE does not accept content_css init parameter

Tags: django, tinymce

I am trying to add CSS to the content of a text box I have working otherwise, but somewhere in the process I lost the ability to link in CSS files to change the iframe's content styling; I had it working before.

Here is my initialization script:

```js
tinymce.init({
  selector: '#id_body',
  mobile: {theme: 'mobile'},
  themes: 'modern',
  height: 480,
  menubar: false,
  plugins: [
    'advlist autolink autosave fullscreen help link lists paste preview searchreplace spellchecker table visualblocks wordcount'
  ],
  toolbar: 'fullscreen | undo redo | formatselect | spellchecker | bold italic underline | strikethrough  subscript superscript blockquote | link | forecolor backcolor | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | removeformat help',
  skin: 'mwd-dark',
  skin_url: '/static/lib/tinymce/skins/mwd-dark',
  content_css: [
    '/static/home/css/reset.css',
    '/static/home/css/tinyMCE.css',
  ],
});
```

`mwd-dark` is a custom skin that I wrote. There are no errors in my console. Navigating to the URLs with `localhost:8000` prepended to them loads the correct files.

Relevant documentation here: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/content-appearance/#content_css

Also in the docs: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/content-appearance/#browsercaching

> Browser caching might cause TinyMCE to not read the contents of a changed CSS file. You’ll see “old” colors & styles.
>
> One solution is to manually clear the browser cache when the file for content_css or editor_css has changed. Another solution is to use an old hack which adds a bogus parameter to the URL containing a present time stamp like “myFile.css?bogus=10023561235”. Possible solutions could look like this:

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',  // change this value according to your HTML
  content_css: 'path/myfile.css?' + new Date().getTime()
});
```

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',  // change this value according to your HTML
  content_css: 'path/myscript.php?myParam=myValue&bogus=' + new Date().getTime()
});
```

I've tried:

- <strike>Clearing the cache</strike> (see accepted answer)
- Adding the "bogus" parameter
- Restarting my browser
- Restarting my computer
- Commenting out the `skin` and `skin_url` parameters, just in case my skin was the cause of issue
- Including a single CSS file at a time (`''` and `['']`)

Any ideas?

**Edit**

*tinyMCE.sass*

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Patua+One|Roboto')
  
@import '_variables'
@import '_mixins'

body
  background-color: $mid-gray
  color: $white
  font-family: $font-body

  a
    color: $light-blue

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6
  font-family: $font-title

  & > a
    text-decoration: underline
    @include transition(color, .15s)

    &:hover
      color: $light-blue

h1, h2
  &, & > a
    color: $yellow

h3, h4
  &, & > a
    color: $orange

h5, h6
  &, & > a
    color: $green

h6
  font-size: 2rem !important

em
  font-style: italic

ul, ol
  padding-left: 2.5rem

ul
  list-style-type: disc

ol
  list-style-type: decimal

pre
  padding: 1rem
  border: 1px solid $light-gray
  border-radius: .25rem
  color: $light-gray
  background-color: $darker-gray

blockquote
  margin-left: 18px
  border-left: .25rem solid $purple
  padding: 1rem
  background-color: $dark-gray

  & > *:last-child
    margin-bottom: 0
```

*tinyMCE.css*

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Patua+One|Roboto");
body {
  background-color: #444444;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: "Roboto", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
body a {
  color: #569cd6;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  font-family: "Patua One", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
h1 > a, h2 > a, h3 > a, h4 > a, h5 > a, h6 > a {
  text-decoration: underline;
  -webkit-transition: color 0.15s ease-in-out;
  transition: color 0.15s ease-in-out;
}
h1 > a:hover, h2 > a:hover, h3 > a:hover, h4 > a:hover, h5 > a:hover, h6 > a:hover {
  color: #569cd6;
}

h1, h1 > a, h2, h2 > a {
  color: #d1d18b;
}

h3, h3 > a, h4, h4 > a {
  color: #bb846e;
}

h5, h5 > a, h6, h6 > a {
  color: #679452;
}

h6 {
  font-size: 2rem !important;
}

em {
  font-style: italic;
}

ul, ol {
  padding-left: 2.5rem;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: disc;
}

ol {
  list-style-type: decimal;
}

pre {
  padding: 1rem;
  border: 1px solid #818181;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  color: #818181;
  background-color: #1e1e1e;
}

blockquote {
  margin-left: 18px;
  border-left: 0.25rem solid #9f62c2;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: #333333;
}
blockquote > *:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

/*# sourceMappingURL=tinyMCE.css.map */
```

Comment: Hi Matt, There are a few questions I need to know to help you further. What version of TinyMCE are you using? Are you using the cloud hosted or self-hosted option? Meanwhile I created the following fiddle which may assist you: https://fiddle.tiny.cloud/hohaab/2

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, I wish I were able to respond earlier. I am using TinyMCE 5, cloud hosted. `reset.css` seems to work now (I was missing the leading slash before), but I still have an issue with my custom CSS. Posting Sass and compiled CSS now.

Comment: I changed your fiddle around a bit, but neither of the CSS files are linking in. https://fiddle.tiny.cloud/3ohaab/4

Comment: Here's an interesting development: in Django, running `(.env) $ python manage.py runserver localhost:8000` renders as explained above, but `(.env) $ python manage.py runserver localhost:9000` works perfectly. Why does the port number make a difference? Should I add a `django` tag to this question?

Comment: I learned this when I ran the VS Code debugger on a different port than the development server and was surprised to see it working. So I also tried testing the development server on port 9000, and it worked. This raises so many questions, such as, "Will this work on port 443 when it comes time to run my development server?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the issue was I wasn't clearing my cache correctly. This browser extension didn't work for me: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/clearcache/

Comment: You should use the browser's feature to clear cache, should the browser change this behaviour the extension will need to update to reflect. As you found out the hard way, it wasn't working as expected. Alternatively, use a brand new Incognito window to confirm changes aren't being cached.